# Get gps coordinates with asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gps, location, google-maps-api-2

i need to get my current coordinates. i try next, but it is does not get result.

```
public class FragmentNear extends SherlockFragment implements
    android.location.LocationListener {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near, null);
    DownloadWebPageTask dw = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    dw.execute("");
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    if (showMFD == 0) { 
    Log.d("myLogs", "-------- onLoChanged " + myLat + " " + myLong);
    myLat = loc.getLatitude();
    myLong = loc.getLongitude();
    Log.d("myLogs", "-------- onLoChangedEnd " + myLat + " " + myLong); 
    }
    }
public void showMFD() {
    showMFD++;
            //my Tasks
            }

private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "Background");
        while (myLat==0)
        {

        }
        showMFD();
        return "";
    }
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
super.onPreExecute();

pb = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
pb.setMessage("Получение данных GPS...");
pb.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
pb.show();
}
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pb.dismiss();

}
}
```

My logic is in the picture[image: image one]

Comment: Too complicated. You can make something mooooore simple

Comment: how? I only want to see progressBar, when coordinates are loading feom gps?

Comment: ahh that you didn't ask in the question ^^

Comment: Getting gps coordinate dosn't takes time. What can takes time is tracing routes on the map or markers. You shouldn't have a progress dialog for something that is a background service.