# Request location updates not updating while driving

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, android-location

I have written this function for requesting location updates:

```
 private void RequestLocations() {
    locationListener = new LocationUpdater();
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,
                100, locationListener);
    } else {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 100,
                locationListener);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,
                100, locationListener);
    }

}
```

I am calling this function in the `onStart()` of a service which I have made a foreground service.
In `locationUpdater` I have implemented `locationListener`. In on location changed I am toasting lat/lang.
It is working fine if I am at a walking speed.
But while I am driving it is not as accurate and fast as it was with walking speed. Even though it is not toasting any `location` if I am at a speed of more than 50 KM/h and as soon as I stop it again starts working and toast a new `location`.
I wanted to make something in which as soon as I move 100 meters away it should toast new `location` whatever the speed is.
Please guide me and if I am wrong at any place make me correct.

Comment: An example of tracker class to use wifi or classic gps (3g, h+, gprs...)[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446619/get-gps-coordinates-with-asynctask)

Comment: how is the GPS signal inside your car?